# Show that an absolute value optimization problem has a local minimum that is not a global minimum

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider a linear optimization problem, with absolute values, of the following form:

\begin{align}
\textrm{minimize} \ c′x+d′y \\ 
\textrm{subject to } Ax+By≤b \\
y_i=|x_i|,
\end{align}

Assume that all entries of B and d are nonnegative.

I have to provide an example to show that if B has negative entries, the problem may have a local minimum that is not a global minimum. Can you please explain why does negative entries cause multiple minima and give an example for the problem?

Comment: For positive $B$ replacing the last constraint with $y\geq |x|$ creates an equivalent problem, and for negative $B$ it does not. So in the first case you have a convex problem, and in the other - not.

Comment: so but how do i show there is a local minima that is not a global minima? Can you provide an example